# What is the concrete difference between a binary file and any other kind of text file?

Tags: operating-systems, c, binary-files

Question based out of curiosity. Why if I copy the code from a binary compiled from c code, and paste it into a new file that I make executable, this new file doesn't act as a binary and execute the code:

[image]

[image]

I guess there are some sort of metadata, but I don't know how it works.

So my question is: What is the real and concrete difference between a binary and a text file?
I cannot find any information on that particular point over the Internet. I'd like to understand that in details.

Comment: Based on the second image, I would suspect because the file has been altered by adding some combination of Line Feed and Carriage Return characters.

Comment: It has nothing to do with "metadata" and everything to do with how you copy it. If you copy it using a text editor then the text editor may apply text formatting rules and reorder or ignore certain data or repair the file by inserting a UTF byte order mark at the start of the file and change Carriage Return bytes to Line Feed or variations of whatever line ending the operating system uses. Even the clipboard might have some "smart" processing. To copy a file properly you should use proper *exact* copying tools. Use the right tools for the job. Text editors for text, copying tools for copying.

Comment: Yes, your text editor is not making an exact copy when you copy this file. Based on the errors you get, I'd say it's displaying unprintable bytes as hexadecimal, then copy-pasting the hexadecimal instead of the actual bytes.